# .NET using block and return; keyword

Tags: .net, using-statement

When I say this

```
using (Entities db = new Entities())
{
    return db.TableName.AsQueryable().ToList();
}
```

Do I by-pass the functionality of using block since I return something, and the method exits before exiting the using block, so I think the using block will not serve to its purpose and dispose the resource.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are incorrect; it *will* be disposed.

The `using` statement compiles to a `try` / `finally` block that disposes the original object in the `finally` block.
`finally` blocks are *always* executed, even if the code inside the `try` block returned a value or threw an exception.

Comment: Finally block doesn't *always* execute ;)  http://thedailywtf.com/Comments/My-Tales.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`using` statement will call `Dispose` of db object before value returning.

Answer (score 2):

Your using statement will indeed succeed. It is akin to the following (which is what the C# compiler will translate the using statement into:

```
Entities db = new Entities();
try
{
    return db.TableName.AsQueryable().ToList();
}
finally
{
    ((IDisposable)db).Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the using block will force the firing of the Dispose object.

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33167

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx